# Java Function Calls Performance Optimization

Tags: java, algorithm, inheritance

I have a class called `HugeClass` where the public method `addButton()`  is defined.

```
public class HugeClass{

public void addButton(){ etc... }
public HugeClass getHugeClass(){ etc... }

...lots of big number crunching logic...

}
```

There is a class called `myController` which calls `getHugeClass()`.

```
public class printController{
   ...
   myController.getHugeClass().addButton();    
}
```

Our client wants us to *not* call `getHugeClass()` in `printController` as the code is very long and eats a lot of memory because it deals with logic in displaying fields on the front end. Is there a better solution?

I am thinking of extending `HugeClass` to `printHugeClass` and then call it in `printController`. Will the performance be better, or will it be the same because it is in-a-way calling the original `HugeClass` and have to run through the entire parent class as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `addButton` needs a properly constructed instance of `HugeClass`, and there is no way you can avoid it (subclassing won't make a difference).

Or you don't need all the details contained in `HugeClass` to call `addButton` and it is maybe time to think about splitting `HugeClass` into smaller independent components.

cf. [this post about SRP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246068/how-do-you-define-a-single-responsibility) (Single Responsibility Principle).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the fact that follwoing statements of `getHugeClass()` are required for `pritnController`.

```
..lots of big number crunching logic...
```

If you can avoid those statements then extending `HugeClass` will resolve your problem when you override `getHugeClass()`.

Comment: hmm, yeah `printController` will only be using the `addButton()` function in `HugeClass` and none of the other huge number crunchinglogic...

Answer (score 0):

How much does `addButton()` depend on the rest of `HugeClass`? If the class got so huge, it might be worth refactoring it and moving the needed parts of `addButton()` into another new class.

Comment: `addButton()` is also used by other controller classes as well, they too also call `getHugeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all it doesn't matter how big your class in java, class loader will load it only once. Your performance issue is related to something else and to find that you should use profiling tool.

My advice: don't do any assumption if you have performance issues, it can be anything. For sure it's not related to how fast java loads classes, unless you don't have logic in static initialization block.